# How to evaluate in a formula in r

Tags: r, formula

Say there is a formula:

```
f1 = as.formula(y~ var1 + var2 + var3)
f1
## y ~ var1 + var2 + var3
```

Then I want to update the formula by adding a named vector `a`.

```
a = 'aaabbbccc'
f2 = update(f1, ~ . + a)
f2
## y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + a
```

This is not what I expected. I want `a` to be evaluated in the formula. Then I tried this:

```
f3 = update(f1, ~ . + get(a))
f3
## y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + get(a)
```

Also failed. What I expected is this:

```
y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + aaabbbccc
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are evaluating these statements in your global environment, then you could do:

```r
f <- y ~ var1 + var2 + var3
a <- as.name("aaabbbccc")
update(f, substitute(~ . + a, env = list(a = a)))
## y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + aaabbbccc
```

Otherwise, you could do:

```r
update(f, substitute(~ . + a, env = environment()))
## y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + aaabbbccc
```

The important thing is that the value of `a` in `env` is a *symbol*, not a string: `as.name("aaabbbccc")` or `quote(aaabbbccc)`, but not `"aaabbbccc"`.

Somewhat unintuitively, `substitute(expr, env = .GlobalEnv)` is equivalent to `substitute(expr, env = NULL)`. That is the only reason why it is necessary to pass `list(a = a)` (or similar) in the first case.

I should point out that, in this situation, it is not too difficult to create the `substitute` result yourself, "from scratch":

```r
update(f, call("~", call("+", quote(.), a)))
## y ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + aaabbbccc
```

This approach has the advantage of being environment-independent, and, for that reason, is probably the one I would use.